# How do you set the twitter user location in JTwitter?

Tags: twitter, jtwitter

I'm building some basic Twitter functionality into my app, and am using the JTwitter JAR to read and set status.

It looks like there is a User class that can be used to set the location, but I just can't figure out how to set it with my GPS coordinates once I've got my Twitter object.

Has anyone been able to set the user.location property using JTwitter?

Thanks,
-Gregg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that JTwitter doesn't support this.

The Twitter API method [`/statuses/update`](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses%C2%A0update) takes `lat` and `long` arguments (or a single `place_id` argument) to specify the location.

Looking at [the source](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter/Twitter.java) (line ~2500), the `updateStatus` method of JTwitter only passes the `status`, `source` and `in_reply_to_status_id` arguments. You'll need to modify the JTwitter source to pass the `lat`/`long` arguments if you want to geotag your tweets.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks for the quick response!
-Gregg

Comment: Just updated the updateStatus function to add the lat and long arguments, and it works great.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the omission!

I've just added support for setting your location to the latest version ([v1.6.2](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php)).
See Twitter.setMyLocation().

NB - location based searches are handled separately via setSearchLocation(), as they need long, lat and radius.